# Ubuntu Server 2 NIC's one for LAN and one for Internet one router

Tags: networking, server

I have done a bit of research but i can find anything for my specific situation.

this is my network infrastructure

[image]

The Ubuntu server has a 6TB LVM that serves media + a newsgroup indexer

I want to have one NIC on the server used for internet use and one for serving LAN

I want to limit the Internet using wondershaper so it doesn't max it out for the other 10+ devices on the network.

the other will be open so that serving media isn't hamstrung when I try and limit one of the interfaces.

The problem is that all traffic is pushed through `eth0`. therefore if I shape `eth0` it also shapes all LAN and internet traffic. I just had a thought about running one of the lan cables directly to the router. At present they are both plugged into the switch.

EDIT: I have now changed it so that eth1 connects to the router directly and Eth0 remains to be connected to the switch

my routing table is as follows.

```
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface  
0.0.0.0         192.168.1.1     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0  
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1000   0        0 eth0  
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     1      0        0 eth1  
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     1      0        0 eth0
```

Comment: Can you be more specific? Where are you stuck? You seem to be asking for a network design to solve your requirements. That question is too local and specific to be asked here.

Comment: Ditto, what is the actual problem in here? Traffic shaping? NIC setup?

Comment: FYI, this is my route table
0.0.0.0,192.168.1.1,0.0.0.0,UG,0,0,0,eth0
169.254.0.0,0.0.0.0,255.255.0.0,U,1000,0,0,eth0
192.168.1.0,0.0.0.0,255.255.255.0,U,1,0,0,eth1  
192.168.1.0,0.0.0.0,255.255.255.0,U,1,0,0,eth0

Comment: Can anyone point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Got this working by editing my /etc/network/interfaces file and setting it as such

auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto eth1
iface eth1 inet static
address 192.168.1.200
netmask 255.255.255.0

auto eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp

up route add -net 192.168.1.0/24 dev eth1

Now all my server internet traffic and LAN traffic are separated.